# How do I configure Webpack for React app using Express.js, GraphQL, client and server folders?

Tags: reactjs, express, webpack, graphql

I could use some direction and tool recommendations. I would like to setup and configure **webpack** for this React app that has both **client** and **server** folders and is using **Express.js and GraphQL**.

[image: React Client and Server]

Someone recommended that I run webpack twice with two configurations:  one for the frontend, one for the backend. But is this the most optimized performance and quickest build?

See the App.js file has Mongo, Express.js and GraphQL setup:
https://github.com/iamshaunjp/graphql-playlist/blob/lesson-36/server/app.js

https://github.com/iamshaunjp/graphql-playlist/tree/lesson-36

Do you have any recommended tutorials that match this app setup?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are more then one pattern, on how you can setup your application project, it usually depends on your how big is your project. However, I would separate Backend and Frontend on webpack as well, by creating separate Webpack configuration files for CLIENT and one for the SERVER, and have two separate servers for both of them.

For instance:

webpack.dev.server.js
webpack.dev.client.js

On the backend you setup server configuration, and on the client you can setup webpack dev server for React application.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to answer. Your response is appreciated! 

For this app, I see that the client-side uses create-react-app so there is no need for webpack on the client and the server-side uses nodemon. 

I was just curious about how to setup webpack for full-stsack apps in the future. Thanks!